# How to return url after upload video from android device to youtube using ytd-android library?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

How to return url after upload video from android device to youtube using ytd-android library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it's. https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/src/com/google/ytdl/ResumableUpload.java#L193

Basically it's the response of videos->insert call. You get a video object, you look it's ID.